# sourcesanspro.sty package \liningnums undefined

Tags: sourcesanspro

In order to use source sans pro font I installed the package `sourcesanspro.sty`. I got it from `ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/fonts/sourcesanspro.zip` and have put it under `/home/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local` and have ran

```
updmap-sys --enable Map=SourceSansPro.map.
```

I am including the package in my `.tex` file as

```
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
(/home/texlive/2010/../texmf-local/tex/latex/local/sourcesanspro/tex/so
urcesanspro.sty
Package: sourcesanspro 2016/12/03 v2.6 Adobe's Source Sans Pro typeface

! LaTeX Error: \liningnums undefined.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because the `sourcesanspro` requires a version of `fontspec` that provides the `\liningnums` command (in order to redeclare it). This command is provided in fontspec v2.2 (2011/09/13) or higher.

There are a couple of options for solving the error:

- Update TeX Live
- Remove line 70 from `sourcesanspro.sty`
- Install an up to date version of `fontspec` and (probably) update all dependencies.

You can, of course, also [file an issue](https://github.com/silkeh/latex-sourcesanspro/issues) for the package (note: I am the maintainer of the `sourcesanspro` package).

Answer (score 0):

If you are here to fix errors with missing font `sourcesanspro.sty` (as this is the top-ranked Google result) then use this under Linux:

```
apt-get install texlive texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-extra -y
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).